# Loop isn't being called in a promise - Javascript NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, asynchronous

I have this code :

```
  console.log("before querying");


  var x = collection.findOne(query)
    .then(function (retrievedData) {

     console.log("after querying");

     for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length || function() {

      console.log("looks like the loop is complete");
      return "";

      }(), false; i++)
        {
         console.log("entering loop...");
        }
    }
```

When I run this code, I see

> before querying

Then the code crashes complaining that the function containing this code has not returned anything.

The actual error is this :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

As you can see, I can't even see `after querying`. The code is running future steps before completing the `.then` part of `findOne`. I haven't posted all of the code since it's long and a bit complex. Could you tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank in advance.

Comment: What is the collection variable?

Comment: @Malice It's a MongoDB collection. I'm using native MongoDB driver.

Comment: what find one returns ?
and what is myArray ?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

Comment: I dont't think findOne returns a promise as you intended...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does mongoose findOne on model return a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35662210/does-mongoose-findone-on-model-return-a-promise)

Comment: @Malice I think the code was working before I was adding that loop. I surely remember the query results inside the `.then` part.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli My question is not related with Mongoose at all.

Comment: Is the `, false` intended ?

Comment: @Malice Yes, I saw it here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5602834/1954132

Comment: I'm 100% sure that findOne returns promise.

Comment: "Then the code crashes complaining that the function containing this code has not returned anything." Post the actual error.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I posted. Thanks.

Comment: Exactly what it says then, `findOne` is returning undefined. I suggest you post a real test case.

Comment: can you try doing this ? `var retrievedData = collection.findOne(query);` and print what you're getting ?

Comment: @Malice I'm getting a promise... Why am I getting a promise? Shouldn't I get a cursor?

Comment: Are you using bluebird or some promise library ?