# NodeJS race condition when retrieving Firebase realtime database node data

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Having an issue with the following nodejs race condition (i believe it called).

I am trying to get the Pool ID <current #> is a

Below is my code and below that is the output:

```
for(;currPool<=lastPool;) {

    console.log("Current Pool ID: " + currPool);

    poolsRef.child(currPool).child("PoolType").once('value', function(snapshot) {
        
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
        
            const poolType = snapshot.val();
            //
            console.log("Pool ID:", currPool, "is a:", poolType , " Style PoolType");

         }

    });

    currPool++;

}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Current Pool ID: 11018
Current Pool ID: 11019
Current Pool ID: 11020
Current Pool ID: 11021
Current Pool ID: 11022
Current Pool ID: 11023
Pool ID: 11024 is a: Survivor  Style PoolType
Pool ID: 11024 is a: Pickem  Style PoolType
Pool ID: 11024 is a: Pickem  Style PoolType
Pool ID: 11024 is a: Pickem  Style PoolType
Pool ID: 11024 is a: Pickem  Style PoolType
Pool ID: 11024 is a: Survivor  Style PoolType
```

How do i get it to display :

```
Pool ID: 11018 is a: Survivor  Style PoolType
Pool ID: 11019 is a: Pickem  Style PoolType
Pool ID: 11020 is a: Pickem  Style PoolType
Pool ID: 11021 is a: Pickem  Style PoolType
Pool ID: 11022 is a: Pickem  Style PoolType
Pool ID: 11023 is a: Survivor  Style PoolType
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a callback inside a loop. There are lots of questions around about that issue, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5602427/javascript-for-loop-callback), but getting your code to work with a for loop isn't ideal.

You're using a for loop to do the job a while loop. If you want to use a for loop, `currPool++` in the for statement. Or use a while loop instead:

```js
while (currPool <= lastPool) {
    // rest of the code
    currPool++
}
```

And according to the docs, `.on` takes a callback, while `.once` *can* take a callback, but also returns a Promise, which would help flatten your code and fix the async issue:

```js
;(async () => {
    while (currPool <= lastPool) {
        console.log("Current Pool ID: ", currPool)
        const snapshot = await poolsRef.child(currPool)
            .child("PoolType")
            .once("value")
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            const poolType = snapshot.val()
            console.log("Pool ID:", currPool, "is a:", poolType , " Style PoolType")
        }
        currPool++
    }
})
```

Comment: I ran your code and nothing happens.

Comment: Oh, the async function wrapping that is just an example to show that you need to be in an async to use an await. Did you invoke it?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how to do so?

Comment: Try adding `()` to the end of it :)